# Instagram API - Unable to generate proper access token (Python)

Tags: python, oauth, instagram

I am getting a JSON return like this:

> {'data': [],
>    'meta': {'code': 200},
>    'pagination': {'deprecation_warning': 'next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead'}}

I am doing the following (where I'm omitting my personal info for the sake of this post):

```
CONFIG = {
    'client_id': '',
    'client_secret': '',
    'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:8515/oauth_callback'
}

api = InstagramAPI(**CONFIG)
```

Then I follow this link (inserting my info):

```
https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token
```

and I get an access token that allows me to do some things like the following:

```
api = InstagramAPI(access_token = access_token)
recent_media, next = api.user_recent_media()
```

but when I try to search for "nhl", for example:

```
url = requests.get('https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nhl/media/recent?access_token='+access_token)
url.json()
```

I get the error result seen at the top of this post.

On the other hand, using the [apigee console to access the instagram API](https://apigee.com/console/instagram?req=%7B%22resource%22%3A%22get_tags_media_recent%22%2C%22params%22%3A%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22template%22%3A%7B%22tag-name%22%3A%22nhl%22%7D%2C%22headers%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22body%22%3A%7B%22attachmentFormat%22%3A%22mime%22%2C%22attachmentContentDisposition%22%3A%22form-data%22%7D%7D%2C%22verb%22%3A%22get%22%7D&apig_cc=1), I get a different access token (by allowing access to my instagram account) that gives the JSON response I'm looking for:

> {"pagination":{"next_max_tag_id":"AQD9K8O5THfHA7yp1waOwivzT ...etc

including the data I want:

> "data":[{"attribution":null,"tags":["nhl","zachayfucale","nhlpa"
>   ...etc

My question is: how can I generate the access token that apigee was able to get?

I have also been able to acquire an access token a different way and I can include this method too if anyone asks, however it does not help solve my problem.

Comment: Here is my other method for getting an access token.
1) put the redirect URL into my browser:
`redirect_uri = api.get_authorize_login_url(scope=["public_content"])`
2) get a code and paste it into my Python file, then I can get a token:
`access_token, user_info = api.exchange_code_for_access_token(code)`
From what I can see, this gives my the same access token as the method included in my post.

Comment: In your data do you have `next_max_id` and/or `min_id`? If so it is complaining about those being deprecated, and to try `max_tag_id` and `min_tag_id`.

Comment: Well they also give me the same warning included in the correct JSON response. The only difference between the search urls in apigee and my python code is the access token.